# Laravel: How to create combinations of product variants and store in database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have the following database structure, but I am struggling to understand how the relationships would work between each table using Laravel.

Also, how would I be able to generate all of the Product Variant Values and Product Variants when updating a product? I don't want to have to do multiple single queries. Is this possible in Laravel?

```
PRODUCTS - hasMany Options
========
product_id product_name
---------- ------------
1          Widget 1
2          Widget 2
3          Widget 3

OPTIONS - hasMany Option Values
=======
option_id option_name
--------- -----------
1         Size SL
2         Color
3         Size SM
4         Class
5         Size ML

OPTION_VALUES - belongsTo Options
=============
option_id value_id value_name
--------- -------- ------------
1         1        Small        (Size SL)
1         2        Large        (Size SL)
2         1        White        (Color)
2         2        Black        (Color)
3         1        Small        (Size SM)
3         2        Medium       (Size SM)
4         1        Amateur      (Class)
4         2        Professional (Class)
5         1        Medium       (Size ML)
5         2        Large        (Size ML)

PRODUCT_OPTIONS - belongsToMany Products and Product Options
===============
product_id option_id
---------- ---------
1          1         (Widget 1; Size SL)
1          2         (Widget 1; Color)
2          3         (Widget 2; Size SM)
3          4         (Widget 3; Class)
3          5         (Widget 4; Size ML)

PRODUCT_VARIANTS - ???
================
product_id variant_id sku_id
---------- ---------- ------
1          1          W1SSCW (Widget 1)
1          2          W1SSCB (Widget 1)
1          3          W1SLCW (Widget 1)
1          4          W1SLCB (Widget 1)
2          1          W2SS   (Widget 2)
2          2          W2SM   (Widget 2)
3          1          W3CASM (Widget 3)
3          2          W3CASL (Widget 3)
3          3          W3CPSM (Widget 3)
3          4          W3CPSL (Widget 3)

VARIANT_VALUES - ???
==============
product_id variant_id option_id value_id
---------- ---------- --------- --------
1          1          1         1        (W1SSCW; Size SL; Small)
1          1          2         1        (W1SSCW; Color; White)
1          2          1         1        (W1SSCB; Size SL; Small)
1          2          2         2        (W1SSCB; Color; Black)
1          3          1         2        (W1SLCW; Size SL; Large)
1          3          2         1        (W1SLCW; Color; White)
1          4          1         2        (W1SLCB; Size SL; Large)
1          4          2         2        (W1SLCB; Color; Black)
2          1          3         1        (W2SS; Size SM; Small)
2          2          3         2        (W2SM; Size SM; Medium)
3          1          4         1        (W3CASM; Class; Amateur)
3          1          5         1        (W3CASM; Size ML; Medium)
3          2          4         1        (W3CASL; Class; Amateur)
3          2          5         2        (W3CASL; Size ML; Large)
3          3          4         2        (W3CPSM; Class; Professional)
3          3          5         1        (W3CPSM; Size ML; Medium)
3          4          4         2        (W3CPSL; Class; Professional)
3          4          5         2        (W3CPSL; Size ML; Large)
```

I have written next to each table name the relationship I think it has, the ones I don't fully understand have `???`

Comment: Laravel has nothing to do with the relationships between tables.

Comment: I know this, but I am specifically using Laravel so I need to know how to do this using Eloquent. As the original post says.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i am going to make an example using two tables to show laravel relationship,

your model should look something like

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class products extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['product_id','product_name'];

    public function options(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\options');
    }
}
```

and the next option model should look something like

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class options extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['option_id','option_detail'];

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\product');
    }
}
```

remember to set a foreign key constraint on the options model like so

```
$table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('product');
```

then you can access the options table through the product table like so

```
$product->options->option_name;
```

Comment: I understand this sort of simple relationship, however, I'm struggling to understand how to do the `product_variants` and `product_variant_values` relationships

Comment: am trying to understand your table, but with difficulties

Answer (score 0):

Not able to get a clear idea from the tables. What I can make out is:

There are `Products` like [Widget 1, Widget2, etc]

Each of the product can have `Variants` like [sku1, sku2, etc]

Further each of the Variants can have `Options/Specifications` like [Size, Color,Class, etc]

Finally each of the `Options\Specification` can have values like [Size: small, Class: professional, etc]

Is that correct?

Can suggest you table structure and relationships only after understanding the data.